# iwd periodically turns off

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, networkmanager, iwd

I use [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd) for my network manager. Whenever I stop using my laptop for a long period of time and come back I notice that my connection is dead and I have to run `sudo systemctl restart iwd` to get it back.

What's causing it to suspend? Is there a way to make it automatically become active again? Is there a configuration file or setting that relates to this behavior?

On Arch.